# Resolving same conflicts again and again when doing rebasing more times

Tags: git

I'm using git.

I'm working on branch, let say it is branch `A`.
And when something changes on `master`, I usually want to take those changes, I'm doing that by rebasing branch `A`.

The problem is that, that I have like 50-60 commits on branch `A` and every time small change happens on `master` I need to do rebase and re resolve all of conflicts.
It would be nice that I could just resolve new conflicts if there is any.

Is there a way to do that in git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see if [`git rerere`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-rerere.html) would help in your case.

You need to activate it first in your current repo:

```
git config --global rerere.enabled 1
```

Then this "**reuse recorded resolution**" script will allow Git to remember how you've resolved a hunk conflict.
See [Rerere Your Boat...](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/08/rerere.html):

[image: git rerere]

Comment: Is that good practice? And that frequent rebasing which I'm doing, is it OK? I'm new to git so I'm opened for any good suggestion.

Comment: @Vajda it (that is "`git rerere`") is a good practice in your case. And your frequent rebase are ok provided you don't publish the history you are frequently rebasing.