# Review multiple git branches as one

Tags: git

We're working with git in a "master" and multiple branches strategy. How many branches? A lot, some quite long living (10 long living "team" branches and 20-30 short living branches off them is normal).

I would like to see a merge of all of the "active" branches (a list of branches I know that are active) - I don't care if this doesn't compile or if some merges fail - I want to see "the big picture".

I've tried working with "checkout master; checkout %branch% -- ." - but I can do that for a single branch since the next branch I'll look at will override the %branch%. Moreover, because of one branch updating from another, I end up looking at the same changed file multiple times.

My next try was to use merge-base between branches I've seen and the next branch. So if I've seen branch1, then my flow is "checkout master; reset --hard; checkout branch1 -- .; (review branch 1); merge-base branch1 branch2 (emits commitX); reset --hard; checkout %commitX%; checkout branch2 -- ."
That would leave branch2 as changes (for my review) but would leave out everything in branch1.

Above is great - but... 1. Identifying the order of branches to do this is hard (working with rule-of-thumb right now). 2. This is very time consuming and error prone. 3. If I make a mistake (choose the wrong branch to start from) I still get to review the same changes twice.

Is there any methodology / tool to aid in such tasks?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend, on your local repo only, to *rebase* those branches on top of master.
With a rebase, commits from one branch which were *already* applied (by the rebase of another branch) won't be replayed.
So the order of rebase don't matter so much (as opposed to multiple merges).
Plus, if you activate [`git rerere`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10481174/6309), you can memorize any merge conflicts that could occur, in order to not have to solve it again.

See also "[Git: How to rebase many branches at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866353/6309)".

Comment: Tested - have issues with conflicts. As said above, I don't care about specific file conflicts - I want to see the big picture. However, on rebase I can either fix each conflict (time-expensive) or skip the entire commit (discarding too much of the change). Any tips on that?

Comment: @RanBiron you could also chose a merge strategy (like ours) in order to not interrupt the merge in case of conflicts (and see the big picture at the end): https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/merge-strategies.txt

Comment: which strategy would you recommend?
Oops - just saw you wrote "ours" - but in rebase "ours" means override the entire commit with the target commit, no?

Comment: @RanBiron yes: "ours" but just to get to the end of the rebase. After that, you can cancel the rebase and redo it whenever you want, this time resolving the conflicts.

Comment: no dice. A commit being fully overridden by existing data (a pervious commit) is making me lose too many changes for the whole effort to be useful.